# PHP can't write big data to csv file

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I'm using the **PHP code to export data to CSV file** from table (Database).

But unfortunately its writing just 98000 rows and i have total 198000 rows in table.

I think total data upto 34mb in the table.

And second thing how can i **download automatically** once the file writing finished. Anyone can help thanks.

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM campaign";
$query = mysqli_query($connection,$que);
$number_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($number_rows >= 1)
{
    $filename = "exported_db_" . date("m-d-Y_hia") . ".csv"; // filenme with date appended
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w"); // open file

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";

    foreach ($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $seperator .= $comma . $name; // write first value without a comma
        $comma = ","; // add comma in front of each following value
    }
    $seperator .= "\n";

    echo "Database has been exported to $filename";

    fputs($fp, $seperator);

    mysqli_data_seek($query, 0); // use previous query leaving out first row

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach ($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . $value; // write first value without a comma
            $comma = ","; // add comma in front of each following value 
        }

        $seperator .= "\n";

        fputs($fp, $seperator);
    } 

    fclose($fp);

}
else {
    echo "There are no records in the database to export.";
}
```

Comment: Could be a timeout. Try to run this script from the console.

Comment: Have a look at ['fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write the data rather than using a loop for each row.

Comment: @odan I have try the mysql code in SSH,  I get correct and complete records, but i should need in php, i'm using it in admin panel.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes i have tried but still same issue only half data writing in file. 
`$que = "SELECT * FROM campaign";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$que);
    $number_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($number_rows >= 1)
 {
$filename = "exported_db_" . date("m-d-Y_hia") . ".csv";
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
$placed_header = false;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if(!$placed_header) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row));
        $placed_header = true;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
fclose($fp);
       }`

Comment: And server speed also fine.  i'm using VPS server and 70GB SSD with many things unlimited.

Comment: Try executing the export through the console with a Shell script. If you are doing it through the admin, I think it will be kind of difficult for you to export that many users. Divide it into parts so that the query won't be that bulky for your memory to handle. I have done this type of scripts when I had to export 100.000+ users to CSV worksheets.

Comment: @OrisSin Thanks Oris, You are right.  but actually at the admin panel i should need to  export table in one csv file. 
I have use the some code for memory and time execution so the issue has solved. 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: You can't use mysql ```INTO OUTFILE```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i put these two line code at the top of file, So i have get correct result. 
I think these code increase the size of caches_memory and execution time. 
Thanks everyone for commenting and discussion.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');
```

Comment: This will work for small data set, what if your data set is 1,000,000,000 records?